# Adding multiple phrases together in phraseto_tsquery

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.6, tsvector

I have been successfully able to concat arrays of single words into strings for to_tsquery but phraseto_tsquery in postgres 9.6 only allows one keyword phrase. Does anyone know of a solution to query a tsvector (whether in Sql or full-text-search features) in such a way where I can (OR/AND) a dynamic amount of phrases into a query. The select blocks are all arrays of text.

First tries:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english','Try not to become a man of successful companies, but rather try to become a man of value')
   @@ (to_tsquery('english','man & become')
       && phraseto_tsquery('english','man of value')
       && phraseto_tsquery('english','company')
       || phraseto_tsquery('english', 'company | man of value')
   );
```

Example of the real world problem searching for animals:

```
-- with statements here of opp_tsv and tp
SELECT
  tp.id,
  tp.keywords, --['giraffes','lions', 'monkeys']
  tp.phrase_keywords, --['pygmy marmocet','African Lion']
  tp.neg_keywords, --['aliens', 'spaceships', 'space']
  tp.neg_phrase_keywords --['Andromedan Alien', 'Nibiru Reptilian']
FROM tp, opp_tsv,
  -- string logic for ts_query
      concat(array_to_string(tp.keywords, ' | ')) AS kws_concat,
      concat(array_to_string(tp.neg_keywords, ' | ')) AS     neg_kws_concat,
      to_tsquery('english', kws_concat) query,
      to_tsquery('english', concat(neg_kws_concat)) neg_query
  -- Case logic for phrase queries

  -- .... -> phrase_query,
      phraseto_tsquery('phrase to search | Need this phrase too')
  -- .... -> phrase_neg_query,

WHERE
  (
    opp_tsv.doc @@ query --pos
    OR
    opp_tsv.doc @@ phrase_query --pos
  )
  AND NOT (
    opp_tsv.doc @@ neg_query --neg
    OR
    opp_tsv.doc @@ phrase_neg_query --neg
  )
ORDER BY rank_cd DESC;
```

Thoughts: 
generate dynamically according to array length

`opp_tsv.doc @@ (phrase_query || phrase_query2)`

or achieve this somehow

`opp_tsv.doc @@ phraseto_tsquery('big messy phrase | more messy wordphrases')`

EDIT:
`SELECT phraseto_tsquery('phrase to search | Need this phrase too')`
result = `'phrase' <-> 'to' <-> 'search' <-> 'need' <-> 'this' <-> 'phrase' <-> 'too'`
What I am looking for is the result of `'phrase<->to<->search' | 'need<->this<->phrase<->too'`

Comment: You could either a) [`CREATE AGGRETAGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html) functions around the `tsquery` operators `&&` and `||`, or b) just simply use the string representation of outputs of these `phraseto_tsquery` calls, using correct parentheses, e.g. `concat('(', array_to_string(tp.phrase_keywords, ') | ('), ')')` ...

Comment: ... but I'm not sure you understood every aspect of the `phraseto_tsquery` function: *Like `plainto_tsquery`, the `phraseto_tsquery` function will not recognize `tsquery` operators, weight labels, or prefix-match labels in its input*, so `phraseto_tsquery('phrase to search | Need this phrase too')` is equivalent to `phraseto_tsquery('phrase to search need this phrase too')`

Comment: Sidenote: you could have a [single predicate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-textsearch.html) in your `WHERE` clause: `opp_tsv.doc @@ ((query || phrase_query) && !!(neg_query || phrase_neg_query))` -- And, if you extract the construction of this `tsquery` into a CTE, you'll more likely use an index for that search.

Comment: I've tried this => `phraseto_tsquery('phrase to search | Need this phrase too')` but this treats the entire input as one phrase. phraseto_query can only take 1 phrase. Thanks for the side note! That can significantly clean up my query. But I still need a programmatic way to add multiple phraseto_query in my query depending on the amount of phrases. @pozs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can define your own aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html) over `tsquery`'s or (`||`) operator:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE tsquery_or_agg(tsquery) (
  SFUNC = tsquery_or,
  STYPE = tsquery
);
```

**Note**: the aggregate above relies on the fact that `tsquery`'s `||` operator is backed by the `tsquery_or(tsquery, tsquery)` function. You can check that with:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_operator
WHERE  oprname  = '||'
AND    oprleft  = regtype 'tsquery'
AND    oprright = regtype 'tsquery';
```

If you don't want to rely on this (undocumented) function's name (even if it's unlikely to be changed), you can create your own function to serve as the base function (`SFUNC`) for your aggregate:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_tsquery_or(tsquery, tsquery)
  RETURNS tsquery
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
  AS 'SELECT $1 || $2';
```

After that, your query will be something like:

```
WITH tp(id, keywords, phrase_keywords, neg_keywords, neg_phrase_keywords ) AS (
  VALUES (42, ARRAY['giraffes', 'lions', 'monkeys']::text[],
              ARRAY['pygmy marmocet', 'African Lion']::text[],
              ARRAY['aliens', 'spaceships', 'space']::text[],
              ARRAY['Andromedan Alien', 'Nibiru Reptilian']::text[])
),
tq(id, query) AS (
  SELECT   tp.id,
           (((SELECT tsquery_or_agg(plainto_tsquery(kw)) FROM unnest(keywords) kw) ||
             (SELECT tsquery_or_agg(phraseto_tsquery(pk)) FROM unnest(phrase_keywords) pk)) &&
             !!((SELECT tsquery_or_agg(plainto_tsquery(nk)) FROM unnest(neg_keywords) nk) ||
                (SELECT tsquery_or_agg(phraseto_tsquery(np)) FROM unnest(neg_phrase_keywords) np)))
  FROM     tp
),
opp_tsv(doc) AS (
  VALUES (to_tsvector('Earth''s African Lions')),
         (to_tsvector('Andromedan Alien''s space monkeys'))
)
SELECT   tp.id,
         tp.keywords,
         tp.phrase_keywords,
         tp.neg_keywords,
         tp.neg_phrase_keywords,
         opp_tsv.doc
FROM     opp_tsv, tp
JOIN     tq USING (id)
WHERE    opp_tsv.doc @@ tq.query
ORDER BY ts_rank_cd(opp_tsv.doc, tq.query) DESC;
```

Also, **if** fields in `tp` can contain phrases like `'big messy phrase | more messy wordphrases'`, then you didn't split your input properly in the first place. You can split such phrases/keywords with the `regexp_split_to_table()` function. With that, the `tq` CTE should look something like:

```
tq(id, query) AS (
  SELECT   tp.id,
           (((SELECT tsquery_or_agg(plainto_tsquery(kw)) FROM unnest(keywords) kwb, regexp_split_to_table(kwb, '\|') kw) ||
             (SELECT tsquery_or_agg(phraseto_tsquery(pk)) FROM unnest(phrase_keywords) pkb, regexp_split_to_table(pkb, '\|') pk)) &&
             !!((SELECT tsquery_or_agg(plainto_tsquery(nk)) FROM unnest(neg_keywords) nkb, regexp_split_to_table(nkb, '\|') nk) ||
                (SELECT tsquery_or_agg(phraseto_tsquery(np)) FROM unnest(neg_phrase_keywords) npb, regexp_split_to_table(npb, '\|') np)))
  FROM     tp
),
```